# How can I extract gtag( 'consent' ) values?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, gtag.js, cookieconsent

Following [Google instructions](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/10718549?hl=en) I am setting consent on a website I am working on.
I am able to set `gtag()` consent through GTM and everything else, I was wondering: how do I get back the values that user set in `gtag('consent')`? (such as `default|update` and `ad_user_data`,`functionality_storage`, etc.)

The Google documentation explains that gtag() has a [`gtag('get')`](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/gtagjs/reference?hl=en#get) option, but [`gtag('consent')`](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/gtagjs/reference?hl=en#consent) seems to be a completely different option on which `gtag('get')` does not work, and I cannot retrieve values set.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags (especially abbreviations). Also, [never link "here"](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/links-should-never-say-click-here/#here-conceals-what-users-are-clicking).